# Proper way to do a True/False/"something" argument in Python

Tags: python, arguments

I have a function in Python which should use a keyword argument, let's call it `foo`, to decide if a certain action should be performed always (`foo=True`), never (`foo=False`) or let an algorithm make the decision (`foo='auto'`). Minimum working example would look something like this:

```
def frobble(bar, foo=True):
    if foo == "auto":
        print("do something automatically")
    elif foo:
        print("always do the thing")
    else:
        print("never do the thing")
    return bar
```

With calls to the function:

```
frobble(my_bar, True)
frobble(my_bar, False)
frobble(my_bar, "auto")
```

And while it works like this (thanks to Python being dynamically typed I guess), I just don't think it's the best solution to let `foo` be a `bool` sometimes and a `str` at other times. Especially considering that a non-empty string is considered `True` and an empty string is considered `False` in Python. This might lead to some issues when comparing it, a.k.a. an empty string might be passed, without desiring the behavior associated with passing `False`. Now, I could of course always let the argument be of `str` type and do `foo='True'` instead of `foo=True` and so on. But that also strikes me as potentially a little confusing to the user.

Is there an obvious (and "pythonic") way out of this that I'm missing?

Comment: Does [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) work for you?

Comment: One option is to check `foo == True` and `foo == False` and raise an exception if it is an unexpected string of something else.

Comment: You can use multiple string values, e.g. `'always'`, `'never'` and `'auto'`. The pythonic way to check for `True` and `False` is  `foo is True` or `foo is False`, to avoid the issues you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

At least on my end, PyCharm complains on the last line with a *type warning*:
`Expected type 'bool', got 'str' instead`.

[image]

I, for one, feel that what you're doing isn't too far-fetched. It might not be the most Pythonic or obvious to have a function parameter sometimes be a `bool` and other times a specific `str` value, however for clarity sake this can potentially be simplified.

This simplification step derives from the fact that you are only checking for a specific `str` value ("auto").

For a specific example, you can use a sentinel object to detect if another type (other than `bool`) is passed in -- similar to how `dataclasses` does it:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import TYPE_CHECKING


# minor optimization: this `class` def block is only useful for IDEs
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    class MissingType:
        pass
    MISSING = MissingType()
else:
    from dataclasses import MISSING


def frobble(bar, foo: bool | MissingType = True):
    if foo is MISSING:
        print("do something automatically")
    elif foo:
        print("always do the thing")
    else:
        print("never do the thing")
    return bar


my_bar = 0

frobble(my_bar, True)
frobble(my_bar, False)
frobble(my_bar, MISSING)
```

If the thought is that it's still more intuitive for a user to pass a string value of "auto" into the function, you can also constrain the value of `str` that are passed into the function, so that the IDE can help warn about any potential typing issues when writing the code.

In this case, I would suggest `typing.Literal`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Literal


def frobble(bar, foo: bool | Literal['auto'] = True):
    if foo == 'auto':
        print("do something automatically")
    elif foo:
        print("always do the thing")
    else:
        print("never do the thing")
    return bar


my_bar = 0

frobble(my_bar, True)
frobble(my_bar, False)
frobble(my_bar, "auto")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with your current `frobble()` but I'll give you an alternate pattern that I find is sometimes helpful.

It is based on using a dictionary of parameter values and methods to determine what work is to be done in the event that the work is not trivial. For trivial work, I would certainly use your pattern.

```py
def frobble(bar, foo="auto"):
    def on_true(bar):
        print("always do the thing")
        return bar

    def on_false(bar):
        print("never do the thing")
        return bar

    def on_auto(bar):
        print("do something automatically")
        return bar

    work = {
        True: on_true,
        False: on_false,
        "auto": on_auto
    }
    
    return work.get(foo, on_auto)(bar)

frobble(1, True)
frobble(1, False)
frobble(1, "auto")
frobble(1)
frobble(1, "?")
```

Note that is treats any "other" value as if it was `"auto"` and that might not be what you want. You might alternatively do:

```py
def frobble(bar, foo="auto"):
    def on_true(bar):
        print("always do the thing")
        return bar

    def on_false(bar):
        print("never do the thing")
        return bar

    def on_auto(bar):
        print("do something automatically")
        return bar

    work = {
        True: on_true,
        False: on_false,
        "auto": on_auto
    }
    
    return work[foo](bar)

frobble(1, True)
frobble(1, False)
frobble(1, "auto")
frobble(1)
frobble(1, "?")
```

That will throw a `KeyError` on `frobble(1, "?")` but you could catch that and throw a `ValueError` instead if you wanted.

If `frobble()` was a thing that you were going to do "a lot" of, I might build a closure to support it:

```py
def make_frobble():
    def on_true(bar):
        print("always do the thing")
        return bar

    def on_false(bar):
        print("never do the thing")
        return bar

    def on_auto(bar):
        print("do something automatically")
        return bar

    work = {
        True: on_true,
        False: on_false,
        "auto": on_auto
    }

    return lambda bar, foo="auto": work[foo](bar)

frobble = make_frobble()

frobble(1, True)
frobble(1, False)
frobble(1, "auto")
frobble(1)
frobble(1, "?")
```